# How to parametrize Impala SQL dates in Where clause

Tags: sql, set, impala

I would like to parametrize my date strings in an Impala `Select` query:

```
WHERE   
    (From_unixtime(Cast(MyDate AS BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') >= '2022-05-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND From_unixtime(Cast(MyDate AS BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') < '2022-05-31 23:59:59.000')
```

My initial attempt:

```
SET VAR:INC_CREATE_START_DATE='2022-06-01 00:00:00.000';
SET VAR:INC_CREATE_END_DATE='2022-06-30 23:59:59.000';    
.
.
WHERE   (From_unixtime(Cast(MyDate AS BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') >=$(VAR:INC_CREATE_START_DATE)
        and From_unixtime(Cast(MyDate AS BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') <$(VAR:INC_CREATE_END_DATE)
```

From the docs: https://impala.apache.org/docs/build3x/html/topics/impala_set.html

> In Impala 2.5 and higher, SET also defines user-specified substitution variables for the impala-shell interpreter. This feature uses the SET command built into impala-shell instead of the SQL SET statement. Therefore the substitution mechanism only works with queries processed by impala-shell, not with queries submitted through JDBC or ODBC.

Is there any other alternatives or workarounds? This is quite fundamental.